# Convert Byte Array to Bitmap Object in wpf

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, arrays

I want to convert byte array to bitmap. I get this byte array from capture card. Rgb24 data include for this array. When i convert this array to bitmap object i got the "Parameter is not valid" error.

This is my byte array
    `myByteArray{byte[921600]}`

```
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(myByteArray);
Bitmap bi = new Bitmap(mStream );
```

and

```
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(myByteArray))
{
Bitmap bi = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mStream );
}
```

and

```
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
mStream.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);
mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
return bm;
}
```

Is this happen because of the size of the array?
Can any one give a method to do this task?
It will be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: How do you get your array?

Comment: I suspect `myByteArray` is neither a `System.Drawing.Image` nor a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. You have to convert it into one.

Comment: `myByteArray{byte[921600]}` isn't valid C#. What is your actual `byte[]` initialization? And there's no `FromImage()` method in `System.Drawing.Image`. If you show invalid code, you're only going to get useless answers.

Comment: I got this array through capture card callback function. This is the method i use for that.

`public static int ShowPIP(VIDEO_SAMPLE_INFO VideoInfo,      IntPtr ptData, int lLength, long tRefTime, int lUserData)
{
byte[] bData = new byte[lLength];
Marshal.Copy(ptData, bData, 0, lLength);
m_ShowPipForm.ShowPIP(VideoInfo,  myByteArray);
return 1;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `myByteArray` is raw image data, this should work:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* p = myByteArray)
    {
        IntPtr unmanagedPointer = (IntPtr)p;

        // Deduced from your buffer size
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, width * 3, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, unmanagedPointer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This is work fine. But When display images the image is up side down.

Comment: i used `bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);` and now i work fine. Thank You

Comment: I think you can use a negative stride to do that (3rd parameter of the constructor): `-(width * 3)`